# What is a good way to structure reducers for a component which is made up of components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a big component which is built up of other, smaller components. Each of the smaller components own a slice of state in Redux.

This big component state is currently created in

```
combineReducers({
  environment,
  router,
  bigComponent,
  ...
})
```

Inside the bigComponent reducer we have

```
combineReducers({
  smallHeader,
  smallComponent1,
  smallComponent2,
  ...
})
```

So essentially, we have state like this

```
{ 
  environment:{...},
  router:{...},
  bigComponent:{
    smallHeader:{...},
    smallComponent1:{...}
    smallComponent2:{...}
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Is this the correct way to structure this?

Is there something to be said for structuring it as:

```
{ 
  environment:{...},
  router:{...},
  smallHeader:{...},
  smallComponent1:{...}
  smallComponent2:{...}
  ...
}
```

?

I've done some research but I can't seem to find a general best practice for this.

Is there a more idiomatic way to structure this?

Comment: State and components are two different things. Don't just blindly copy the hierarchy of components to your state. Use logical hierarchies in the state. Usually component hierarchy will be rather deep but state can have only several levels. Use the top level components to read part of the state and pass it down as props to subcomponents.

Answer (score 0):

I like to follow the *Container Pattern*. Have Container components which are connected to Redux. The Container components pass props to children (which are not connected).

One reducer/state per container. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Sorry to reply so late (3 weeks). I was speaking more along the lines of folder structure with combineReducers here. I have container components within container components and I was wondering how to structure their reducers.